Configure Redrive Allow Policy for Dead-Letter Queue using CDK
I am using AWS CDK on Python and would like to create SQS which has dead letter queue and want to add redrive allow policy to let only associated queue and redrive it.
Here is my sample code
from aws_cdk import sqs
from constructs import Construct

class MyStack(Stack):
    def __init__(
        self,
        scope: Construct,
        construct_id: str,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

    dead_letter_queue = sqs.Queue(
        self,
        dead_letter_queue_name,
        queue_name=f"{dead_letter_queue_name}",
        redrive_allow_policy=sqs.RedriveAllowPolicy(
            redrive_permission=sqs.RedrivePermission.BY_QUEUE,
            source_queues=[queue], # Require source IQueue (source queue) to be created first
        ),
    )
    queue = sqs.Queue(
        self,
        queue_name,
        queue_name=f"{queue_name}",
        dead_letter_queue=sqs.DeadLetterQueue(
            max_receive_count=3,
            queue=dead_letter_queue, # Require dead letter queue to be created first
        ),
    )

Both of them require each other to be created first, I am just newbie on CDK so how can I solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

I workaround this issue by manually attach policy to dead letter queue instead of using redrive allow policy.
For minimum policy, please see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-dead-letter-queue-redrive.html
from a ws_cdk import (
  aws_sqs as sqs,
  aws_iam
)
from constructs import Construct

class MyStack(Stack):
    def __init__(
        self,
        scope: Construct,
        construct_id: str,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

    dead_letter_queue = sqs.Queue(
        self,
        dead_letter_queue_name,
        queue_name=f"{dead_letter_queue_name}",
    )
    queue = sqs.Queue(
        self,
        queue_name,
        queue_name=f"{queue_name}",
        dead_letter_queue=sqs.DeadLetterQueue(
            max_receive_count=3,
            queue=dead_letter_queue, # Require dead letter queue to be created first
        ),
    )
    dead_letter_queue.add_to_resource_policy(
      statement=aws_iam.PolicyStatement(
          actions=[
              "sqs:StartMessageMoveTask",
              "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
              "sqs:DeleteMessage",
              "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
              "sqs:CancelMessageMoveTask",
              "sqs:ListMessageMoveTasks",
          ],
          effect=aws_iam.Effect.ALLOW,
          principals=[aws_iam.ServicePrincipal("sqs.amazonaws.com")],
          resources=[dead_letter_queue.queue_arn],
      )
  )
  dead_letter_queue.add_to_resource_policy(
      statement=aws_iam.PolicyStatement(
          actions=["sqs:SendMessage"],
          effect=aws_iam.Effect.ALLOW,
          principals=[aws_iam.ServicePrincipal("sqs.amazonaws.com")],
          resources=[queue.queue_arn],
      )
  )

